# Applying statements in Models with Eloquent in Laravel

Tags: sql, sql-server, laravel, eloquent, model

I'm using Laravel 5.1, and I'm trying to convert all my queries made with QueryBuilder to Eloquent.

The point is that in a particular view, I need to execute previously some "set ansi statements".

Nowadays I can do this in my Controller as follows to get some records:

```
 $db = DB::connection('my_connection_1');
 $db->statement('SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON');
 $db->statement('SET ANSI_PADDING ON');
 $db->statement('SET ANSI_NULLS ON');

 $select = $db->select('SELECT * FROM name_of_table/view');
```

This works perfectly, but I did not like to work that way, so I created a Model to access this Table/View that looks like this:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class NameFromModel extends Model
{

    protected $connection = 'my_connection_1';

    protected $table = 'name_of_table/view';

}
```

So, in the Controller, now, the code should looks like the next one:

```
$select = NameFromModel::get();
```

But obviously, needs some extra code to be able to add the statements that needs in this Model.

I don't want to apply these statements in all queries, just in this Model.

I will appreciate any help you can provide.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You can do these statements when the target event dispatched in your model as can be read from [laravel 5.1 eloquent events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#events).
For example for *creating* event in your AppServiceProvider:

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        \App\NameFromModel::creating(function () {
            \DB::connection('my_connection_1');
            $db->statement('SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON');
            $db->statement('SET ANSI_PADDING ON');
            $db->statement('SET ANSI_NULLS ON');
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: It's confusing because seems that's this solution it's only if you create (update, save, delete or restore...) a record from this model. But actually, I just need to do a select. Anyway, I can't see the solution you try to provide me.